# Always get "Unknown modifier" when using a RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use the second single line RegEx with `preg_match()` from this page:
http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Always get:

> Unknown modifier '\' in ...

Can anybody tell me how to use this RegEx correctly with `preg_match()` or is the RegEx incorrect?

Comment: What does your actual `preg_match` look like?  If you are using that regex as-is, I would suggest putting a '#' before and after it, as PHP requires those separators to be present.

Comment: http://www.php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your regex with delimiters (in this case, I suggest `~` because it's not being used anywhere in your regex) and use mode modifiers (`~i`) instead of inline modifiers (`(?i)`):

```
~\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))~i
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `filter_var` makes it easier to match emails, ips, urls without using a regex.

Try to use this:

```
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) {
    // match!
}
```

List of all filters:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Comment: *"The problem the pattern attempts to solve: identify the URLs in an arbitrary string of text"* - it's not the same as validating.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) section in the PHP manual:

> When using the PCRE functions, **it is required that the pattern is
>   enclosed by delimiters**. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>   non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~).